# Responsive email, not working for Android (works fine in iOS and Windows Phone)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

so I have this html email that is supposed to be responsive, I am using media queries and searched for an answer but nothing seems to get the job quite done. Basically the problem is that I want the text portion of the email to change it's width but it is not doing it (the color is changing, I put it there to check if it was that the media query was not being executed. I'm guessing it's an html issue, but I can't quite get the job done. Any help would be appreciated. Here's my html:

```
<html>
<body>
<table class="container" width="600" align="center">
<tr>
<td>
    <div class="header">
        <img src="www.testimg.com" width="600" height="200">
    </div>

    <table class="textAreaT">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="textarea">Sample text which is supposed to be shrinking in smaller screens but certainly isn't. Color is changing so no idea why the width is not working as expected. HELP!!</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>



    <div class="footer"></div>

    <div class="disclaimer">
         ©2015 Marinello Schools of Beauty, All rights reserved.
    </div>

    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Also here is my css:

```
<style type="text/css">

body {
    font: 100%/1.4 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #000;
}


h1 {
    font-face: 100%/1.4 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #004586;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 17px;
}


h2 {
    font-face: 100%/1.4 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #004586;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 15px;
}


span {
    font-face: 100%/1.4 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-color: #000;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 145%;
}

ul, li {
    font-face: 100%/1.4 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #004586;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.container {
    width: 600px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

a img { 
    border: none;
}

a:link {
    color: #004586;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:visited {
    color: #004586;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:hover {
    color: #666666;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:active {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: underline;
}


.header {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-color: #004586;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.textarea {
    width: 600px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .textarea {
        max-width: 450px !important;
        width: 450px !important;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        margin-bottom: 12px;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        color: red !impotant;
    }

    .container {
        width: 100% !important;
    }

    .textAreaT {
        max-width: 450px !important;
        width: 450px !important;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        margin-bottom: 12px;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 600px) {
    .textarea {
        max-width: 450px !important;
        width: 450px !important;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        margin-bottom: 12px;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        color: red !impotant;
    }

    .container {
        width: 100% !important;
    }

    .textAreaT {
        max-width: 450px !important;
        width: 450px !important;
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        margin-bottom: 12px;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
    }
}

<!--
.footercontainer {
    width: 600px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-color: #004586;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-top: 10px;
    position: relative;

}
-->

.footer {
    width: 600px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-color: #004586;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.disclaimer {
    width: 600px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    font-face: 100%/1.4 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 8px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

Again guys, thank you very much in advance for any help you can provide.

PD: I'm testing in Android 2.3 and 4.2 (Litmus)

Comment: Did you tried to use inline styles instead <style>?

Comment: You can't inline media queries.